# How to pass event to element which has lower layer

Tags: events, svg

```
<span style="display:inline-block; width:40px; height:40px;  border:red solid thin; "><svg ><script type="application/ecmascript">     function circle_click1(evt) {
  alert("red");
}</script><defs>
 <clipPath id="clipPath">
      <rect x="15" y="15" width="40" height="40" />
  </clipPath> </defs><circle  onclick="circle_click1(evt)" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" style="fill: red; clip-path: url(#clipPath); " /></svg></span><span style="display:inline-block; width:40px; height:40px; position: relative; left:-20px; border:blue solid thin; "><svg> <script> function circle_click2(evt) {
  alert("blue");
}</script><defs>
  <clipPath id="clipPath2">
      <rect x="15" y="15" width="40" height="40" />
  </clipPath>  </defs>  <circle onclick="circle_click2(evt)" cx="25" cy="25" r="20"
      style="fill: blue; clip-path: url(#clipPath2); " />
```

I use above code to show two svg circles, one is red, the other is blue, there is a span container for each circle and one span overlap another. How to make the red circle which under the blue rectangle span has mouse event ?

Comment: Do you mean you don't want the blue circle to be clickable, or anything clicked on the blue then does something to the red one ?

Comment: I want the red circle to response the click event.

Comment: To which click event, there are two there. You need to be more precise saying what you want to happen when you click on which bit. What do you want to happen when you click on the blue circle, what do you want to happen when you click on the red circle. Do you want one click handler that works for the whole lot (eg could you put them in a group and put the click handler on that).